# The annotation @Qualifier is disallowed for this location - OAuth2Config file

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-annotations

I'm configuring **OAuth2** for my **Spring Boot** application. I found a link explaining about it https://gigsterous.github.io/engineering/2017/03/01/spring-boot-4.html.

This is my OAuth2Config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("appUserService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

}
```

This is my appUSerService file:

```
@Service("appUserService")
public class AppUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        return appUserRepository.findOneByUserName(userName);
    }

}
```

But i'm getting this error: 
Multiple markers at this line
    - The annotation **@Qualifier** is **disallowed** for this location
    - The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type 
     Qualifier.

Thanks in advance for the help/suggestions.

Comment: Show the full package name of the class `Qualifier`.

Answer (score 0):

**@Resource** worked instead of keeping @Autowired and @Qualifier.